# Compare two user lists in bash

Tags: linux, bash, passwd

I have two different user lists.  I need to compare the users and make sure they exist in both files.  One is the passwd file, and another is a flat file for that has the usernames and other information that I can extract a sorted username list from.

This gives me a sorted list of the usernames:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut --fields=1 | sort -k1.2
```

Is there a better way to do this number one, and number two how do I then compare it the other user list from the other file? If the user does not exist I will be adding it to the flat file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you using process substitution with bash, diff, awk, and sort:

```
diff <(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort) <(sort your_other_list_file)
```

This assumes your `your_other_list_file` only contains usernames, one per line. Can't help you parse that unless you post an example line.

Answer (score 3):

comm -3 <( (cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd | sort) ) <(sort file2)

I like this best, it's a one-liner, avoids awk, and `comm` gives you options to give you entries unique to list1, list2, or commonalities to both.  Also cutting before sorting gives sort shorter strings to work with so it might be faster on longer lists.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your flat file looks like this example:

```
data info username number status
```

Then you could do this:

```
join -v 1 -1 1 -2 3 <(sed 's/:/ /g' /etc/passwd | sort) <(sort your_file) >> your_file
```

That appends lines that appear in file one (`-v 1`) that don't appear in file two to the end of file two. The fields for matching are field 1 for file one and field 3 for file two. The `sed` command compensates for the password file being colon-delimited and the flat file being space delimited. You can adjust field numbers and delimiters to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily see which lines are not present from one file to another with grep:

```
fgrep -vxf file1 file2
```

It will show lines present in file2 but not in file1. (Note the order of the arguments)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/passwd1 | cut -d':' -f1 | sort > passwd_file1
cat /etc/passwd2 | cut -d':' -f1 | sort > passwd_file2
diff passwd_file1 passwd_file2
```

You could also just sort it and diff it without cutting to get full information.

Comment: I changed my question around a bit, it's not really two comparable files.

Comment: I can tell you what not do to. I was trying something similar to (command alerted slightly so that no one copies it without thinking):
for i in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d' :' -f1`; do `if [ "grep $i /etc/passwd3" ]; then echo $i; fi`; done

It didn't do what I was expecting (list the usernames in both), instead it executed each username as a command. All well and good until it gets to the username "halt". There goes my uptime.

Comment: sort both files, and then join them, for example:
join -1 1 -2 1 /etc/passwd /your/file

Comment: I need to re-create the user in the flat file with the extra parameters as well.

Comment: You're not being specific enough, you tell us that they are not the same format and not comparable, but expect us to be able to determine which information needs to get into the mystery file.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to be cryptic, but it's an internal file that I cannot give examples for.  All that I can say is that the usernames are equal and I can parse out the usernames from the file.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `diff`? Just execute `diff file_a file_b` and you'll get a diff file with all the changes. After that you can simply filter on a `+` to get the missing lines.

Do note that for `diff` to work properly you'll probably need to sort it first.

Comment: I changed my question around a bit, it's not really two comparable files.